# Adding path to pythonpath in dockerbuild file

Tags: python, docker

Using dockerbuild file, how can I do there something like:
`export PYTHONPATH=/:$PYTHONPATH`

using `RUN` directive or other option

Comment: You can use ENV directive in the dockerfile `ENV PYTHONPATH=...`

Comment: Can you please write the equivalent to the above?

Comment: What is the expected value of the varible? In most base containers, the env variable $PYTHONPATH is unset. So the equivalent would be `ENV PYTHONPATH=/:`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `Dockerfile`, either of these should work:

- Use the `ENV` instruction (`ENV PYTHONPATH="/:$PYTHONPATH"`)
- Use a prefix during the `RUN` instruction (`RUN export PYTHONPATH=/:$PYTHONPATH && <do something>`)

The former will persist the changes across layers. The latter will take effect in that layer/`RUN` command